# Why does string EndsWith and StartsWith equals true with string.Empty

Tags: c#

Why does string EndsWith and StartsWith equals true with string.Empty in c#
and explain the reason behind this, why it is this way.

```
string str = "string";
Console.WriteLine(str.EndsWith(string.Empty));   // returns true... why?
Console.WriteLine(str.StartsWith(string.Empty)); // returns true... why?
```

Answer (score 5):

The empty string is a substring of every string and also occurs in every possible position – that includes at the start and the end.

Picture it this way: Each character in the needle has to occur in the same sequence at the start or end of the string. And the universal quantifier (∀) over an empty set is always true.

Comment: It still doesnt explain why...

Answer (score 3):

Why shouldn't it?

```
string.Empty + "string" + string.Empty = "string"
```